# Left 4 Dead 2 accuracy - when can I stop shooting?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I'm trying to break 75% accuracy on Left 4 Dead 2.  I can consistently get about 60% accuracy with either of the automatic shotguns, but when I try with the M-16, my percentage drops to the high 40s.

Assuming that my shooting habits don't change from firearm to firearm, the only thing that I can think of that would cause this drop is the fact that the shotgun's slower firing rate means that every common infected is guaranteed to get one *and only one* round.  With the M-16, it's very likely that a particular bullet will kill the zed, but by the time I realize that it's dead, I've fired once or twice more.

My question is: **Do bullets fired at dead or dying zombies* count against your accuracy rating?**
This has a follow-on question:
**What about bullets fired at zombies that a teammate has also been firing at?**  If your teammate kills the zombie, does your accuracy decrease for those bullets you fired at it?

(*And before you say it, yes, I know that *all* zombies are dead)

Comment: Bullets in Left 4 Dead 2 should be hitscan, which means there's no travel time, which means it's not possible for a zombie to die with the bullet's mid-flight.

Comment: The M16 normally has lower accuracy than the rest. It's a machine gun - it always fires a bullet or two more than you needed - which is only [one or two](http://www.zombicidal.com/weapons-items/firearms/#assaultrifle), by the way, so keep those bursts short.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recomend using hunting rifle, I've reached 95% accuracy at the end of a co-op campaign while using it once. But to answer your question:
1) Accuracy doesn't count kills, it counts hits. As long as you hit your targets you're doing well. And it doesn't matter who else is shooting the target.
2) From what I noticed (but it's actually hard to measure) bullets count as hits as long as they hit the hitbox and it doesn't matter if the target is already dead or not. Tank's hitbox disappear a second later than his actuall death. If you continue to shoot him, that's still going to count as hits. Common zombies' hitbox disappear a split second after their death.

P.S. L4D stats are often so bugged that I feel sorry for your trying to reach a certain value at accuracy...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an automatic rifle, I recommend you to use short bursts of two ore three shots. From my tries, this was the most accurate way to inflict as much damage as possible without missing.